# How to set indentation of array's elements in Java Script source code in Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, coding-style, formatting

How can I configure formatting options in Eclipse for Java Script source code so that having this code:

```
var o = {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        columns: [<cursor here>{header: 'Column One'}],
    }],
};
```

after pressing `Enter` I get this

```
var o = {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        columns: [
            {header: 'Column One'}],
    }],
};
```

instead of the default:

```
var o = {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        columns: [
                  {header: 'Column One'}],
    }],
};
```

I'd like to have initializers of array's elements indented with one level of indentation (tab in my case) not aligned with the opening bracket. I can't get the right indentation even manually - given this code

```
var o = {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        columns: [
{header: 'Column One'}], // cursor at the beginning of this line
    }],
};
```

after pressing `Tab` twice I get the same indentation as after pressing `Enter` above.
I'm using JavaScript Development Tools ver. 1.3.0.v201103031824 from Eclipse Web Tools Platform.

Comment: There's an issue in Eclipse Bugzilla related to this request: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=356606

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps albeit a bit late...

You can change the Formatter for JavaScript in Eclipse->Preferences 
Goto JavaScript->Code Style->Formatter

Edit to create your custom profile and make changes to the following:
In the Line Wrapping Tab

- Change *Default Indentation for array Initializers* to "1"
- Select Expressions->Array Initializers and set the line wrapping policy as desired. Wrap all except first seemed OK to me.
- Change *Indentation policy* for the above to "Indent by one"
- Check the ***Force split*** box to have the effect always regardless of whether or not a Wrap is required.

Comment: After setting above options the preview looks ok but in editor I still get the same formatting as described in question.

Comment: Edited my answer to get the desired effect, but it requires that you use the Formatting shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+F) on the array declaration. The Enter still does not seem to take the formatting into account.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost did you get the desired effect based on my edit?